# Binance get_my_trades error Python

Tags: python, binance

cuando intento consultar get_my_trades en binance me sale este error

> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/binance/client.py",
> line 230, in _handle_response
> raise BinanceAPIException(self.response) binance.exceptions.BinanceAPIException: APIError(code=0): Invalid JSON
> error message from Binance:   ERROR: The request could not be
> satisfied
>
> ## 413 ERROR
>
> ### The request
> could not be satisfied.
>
> Bad request. We
> can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time.
> There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again
> later, or contact the app or website owner.  If you
> provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to
> troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront
> documentation.
>
> ```
> Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront) Request ID:
> ```

Este es mi codigo

```
symbols = client.get_all_tickers()

moneda = []
for simbolo in symbols:
    moneda.append(simbolo['symbol'])
    

for monedas in moneda:
    trades = client.get_my_trades(symbol=moneda)
    print(trades)
```

Answer (score 1):

Amigo he corrido tu código y creo que el problema es el límite, intenta poner el parámetro `limit=tulimite` (en mi caso yo usé 1) si tu cuenta no tiene trades en ese ticker te devolverá llaves vacías `[]` y otro consejo, debido a la gran cantidad de tickers la api puede devolver `Too much request` recuerda que se permiten sólo 1200 peticiones por minuto, la cual puedes solucionar de la siguiente manera:

```
import time
symbols = client.get_all_tickers()
moneda = []
for simbolo in symbols:
    moneda.append(simbolo['symbol'])
for monedas in moneda:
    trades = client.get_my_trades(symbol=moneda,limit=tulimite)
    print(trades)
    time.sleep(.05) #con 50 ms será suficiente
```

espero te funcione